# Nuget package manager console - Package does not contain a manifest

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, package-managers

I suddenly get this error on every package I try to update/reinstall in my project.. How can I start to debug this problem? Does the package manager create a log file with more details than this? Where is the manifest that it does not find?

Same package in different project but same solution works fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I m having the same issue.I think it might be a nuget version issue.I tried to install the package at my visual studio 2013, with nuget version is 2.12.0.817 and i got the same error. Then i tried installing the same package at my visual studio 2015, running nuget version 3.4.4.1321 and the package got installed successfully. So if i were you i would check my nuget version.

Answer (score 0):

I faced two different problems:

- the tool used to compress the folder (like Compress-Archive)
  adds the root folder name inside the compressed file
  https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14312
- the tool used to compress the folder has a compression method incompatible
  with the client trying to unzip the .nupkg file.
  For example, in my case the **System.IO.Compression.ZipFile** class used to compress the content of the folder was incompatible with the client extraction capabilities.
  However, when I manually compressed the same folder content
  with **Right-click\Send To\Compressed (Zipped) Folder**, it was working fine.